# Laravel 5 trouble autoloading class - Class Not Found Error

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am attempting to autoload my classes. I create a folder app/Classes with a file Foo.php and a file Bar.php.

In composer.json I have the folder referenced

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Classes/"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": ["app/Library/myFunctions.php"]
},
```

Follow this by

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Verified the vandor/autoload/autoload_classmap.php has both

```
'Bar' => $baseDir . '/app/Classes/Bar.php',
'Foo' => $baseDir . '/app/Classes/Foo.php',
```

I put a simple function in each class like:

```
<?php 
    class Bar {
        public function __construct(){
            echo 'Bar';
        }
    }
?>
```

Then I attempt to reference it

```
new Bar;
```

and receive the error

```
FatalErrorException in LoginController.php line 24:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Login\Bar' not found
```

NOW..... to solve the error I put

```
new \Bar;
```

and we are good.

Is there some reason I need the '\' in my code. This fix is nowhere for me to find in docs, I just noticed it on laracasts and added it in frustration, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a namespacing issue. It looks like setting `"app/Classes/"` as a classmap sets classes in there as being in the root namespace. So Foo and Bar are both in the root. Your controller seems to be in this namespace:`App\Http\Controllers\Login`. Unless otherwise specific class names are taken as relative to the current namespace, so just using Foo makes it look up the class `App\Http\Controllers\Login\Foo`., where as putting a slash in front stops it being relative and goes straight to the root (think folders or URLs).

If you want it be tidier, you can put `use Foo;` at the top, below the namespace line if there is one, but before anything else.

Comment: Looks Like I can add use App\Classes\Bar at the top then do new Bar; OR I can skip that and do new \App\Classes\Bar; But I think the point is I am testing this from a deeper folder, and most of the examples I am following are on the root folder....

Comment: Hmm, that's weird - that \Bar works, but the namespace is actually \App\Classses\Bar. I know that Laravel does do some sneaky tricks with class names a lot, but that does still seem weird.